# Puppeteer launch a new tab in current window, not new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I've tried just about everything and can't seem to figure out how to get Puppeteer to work in my current browser window (Where I'm logged in to Chrome) rather than a new cache-less logged out browser. Here's my current config setting up everything. I've tried starting chrome prior with remote debug port, loading user data in args for launching puppeteer, launching both Chromium and my current Chrome installation path, etc. Here's my current code:

```
const opts = {
  logLevel: 'info',
  output: 'json'
};


const chrome = await chromelauncher.launch( {port:9222 });
opts.port = chrome.port;

// Connect to it using puppeteer.connect().
const resp = await util.promisify(request)(`http://localhost:${opts.port}/json/version`);
const {webSocketDebuggerUrl} = JSON.parse(resp.body);
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl, 
  args: ["--disable-extensions"]});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
```

I've run out of resources to look, if something looks off please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: `loading user data in args for launching puppeteer`, it says you tried this. However, you did not mention where are you trying this and why you are using `--disable-extensions` args or using a browserWSpoint. :)

Comment: Hi! I loaded it in args with --user-data-dir and as an argument to puppeteer as well

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a `userDataDir` to reuse the cache.

```
puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: 'PATH TO DATA FOLDER',
})
```

You can find your data directory here,

- Windows 7, 8.1, and 10: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
- Mac OS X El Capitan: `Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`
- Linux: `/home/<username>/.config/google-chrome/default`

Another way is to open `chrome://version` and pick the path from there,

[image]

Now, remove the `Default` and you will get your data directory,

- [Profile Path] `C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
- [User Data Dir] `C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

So the code will look like,

```
puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: `C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`, 
  // <-- notice I used backtick to avoid writing backslashs
})
```

Learn more about data directory [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+show/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).

Another interesting argument is the `--profile-directory`, You can name a profile and use that.

```
--profile-directory=Default
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response - I tried the above as listed here: `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        userDataDir: "C:\\Users\\scott\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});`

Comment: With no success - still launching a new window, still without my user data

Comment: I did not write proper answer, sorry for that, gimme 1 minute to update it.

Comment: There you go, try this and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've tried this before, because it does launch a new tab in the browser, but crashes with the following answer: `error Error: Failed to launch chrome!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (C:\Users\scott\Documents\x\x\x\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:342:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (C:\Users\scott\Documents\x\x\x\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:332:60)
    at ChildProcess.emit
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)`

Comment: `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        userDataDir: "C:\\Users\\scott\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});`

Comment: The above is the current configuration, i've tried with and without the executable path to chrome

Comment: This is so weird error. I ran it perfectly fine. Can you write down the puppeteer and operating system version?

Comment: Sure thing, Puppeteer is: v1.13.0, Operating system is Win10 x64, and chrome verison is: 72.0.3626.121. I have no idea what's wrong and I agree, it is weird, because i've googled everything and not sure what's going on. I also went to the npm site for puppeteer and made sure I had all of its dependencies.

Comment: Can you post your code where you are using `.launch`?

Comment: Yeah it's the above in this comment thread: `.launch({ headless: false, executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', userDataDir: "C:\\Users\\scott\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data" }); const page = await browser.newPage(); await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});`

Comment: The original question has `.connect`, so I suggest a new project just containing the minimal reproducable code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is useful to your case as I use the Chromium browser and not my system chrome browser but I save the Chromium setting inside the project PeaceOut.
I'm still learning how to use puppeteer so might not be doing everything the best way.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
 // slowMo: 250 // slow down by 250ms
 // executablePath <string> Path to a Chromium or Chrome executable to run
    userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\TeDev\\Scrape\\PeaceOut\\bdata' 
 // userDataDir <string> Path to a User Data Directory.
});
const page = await browser.pages();
await page[0].setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 1080 })
console.log(`Trying to access ${URL}`);
await page[0].goto(URL);  // use tab 0, so Chromium doesn't show a blank tab.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add --new-window argument when launching

Comment: Can you explain how this command solve the problem ?